# .Select is not supported in Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq

Tags: c#, linq, azure, select, boolean

Hello fellow programmers

I have a technical inquiry regarding to the code that I am working on C# for RESTful / services / API in .NET Framework. I was trying to make a query based on predicate that will return boolean response and one of the ways that I have known is by using .Select or .Any. However, neither of them has worked perfectly well with my solution as I got an error saying either "Method 'Select' is not supported.\r\nActivityId:.." or "Method 'Any' is not supported.\r\nActivityId:.." correspondingly. Here is a block of code where I use the method on predicate:

```
var users = await this.GetEntitiesAsync(x =>
                          x.Type == typeof(models.User).FullName &&
                          x.TenantId == tenantId &&
                          x.Outlets.Select(y => y.Id.ToString()).Contains(storeId) &&
                          (x.UserName == userName && (x.Password == password || x.Pin == pin)));
```

and here is a breakdown of GetEntitiesAsync() function:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetEntitiesAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (!CollectionIdExists())
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(CollectionId));


        using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndPoint), AuthKey))
        {
            IDocumentQuery<TEntity> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId))
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

            List<TEntity> results = new List<TEntity>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TEntity>());
            }
            return results;
        }

    }
```

In addition, I would really prefer to modify the predicate as the function is used on other services and if I make changes on the function, it may affect other functionalities within the program. However, as long as there is relevant solution, I will definitely give it a try. Furthermore, I am kind of new around the development within the environment that I am currently working on, so apologies for the trouble. I do kind of need to get this resolved as quickly as I can and I have been doing some intensive research for the resolution as I post this discussion. Thanks for your concern in advance. May you have a blast one! :)

Answer (score 0):

This line in your predicate

```
x.Outlets.Select(y => y.Id.ToString()).Contains(storeId)
```

is invalid.  You cannot return a projection in your predicate.  Instead, you should update it to use `.Where()` and specifically look for Outlets where the Id matches your storeId.

```
x.Outlets.Where(y => y.Id.ToString() == storeId)
```

Comment: Hi Dave

Thanks for your response. I tried your suggested code before, however GetEntitiesAsync() function is expecting boolean return, so if I applied that onto my predicate, it would not work as it would return an object instead of boolean. Furthermore, I did try .ToBoolean(), but apparently same as .Select(), that is not supported in Azure Linq. Anyway, that is not really my work, I was just trying to help a colleague and he said that that line of code is not used anymore. Thanks for your kind thought, though. :)

Regards,
Jonas